# Using Outlook to Read RSS Items. Want to delete Item if Web Page has 'Page Not Found'

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using MS Outlook to read a bunch of forums on SO.  I have code that loop through items and checks for "[on hold]" or "[closed]" in the subject line.   This works fine.  I'm trying to modify the code a bit to do the following:

```
#1)  look for language that reads "View article..."
#2)  click this link (need to get innerText)
#3)  scan the page that opens and check for language that reads "Page not found"
```

If this is true, I want to delete the current 'myItem' and move to the next 'myItem'.  I know my code below is close, but instead of '.navigate "https:' etc., I need to get the innerText from the "View article..." hyperlink, click that, and scan the page that opens for the language "Page not found".  How can I do that?

```
Sub GetRssItem()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim subFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItem As Object
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)
For i = 1 To 27
Set subFolder = myFolder.Folders(i)
   Debug.Print subFolder
      For Each myItem In subFolder.Items
        If InStr(myItem.Subject, "[on hold]") > 0 Or _
            InStr(myItem.Subject, "[closed]") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print myItem.Subject
            myItem.Delete
        End If

        If myItem.Body Like "*" & "View article..." & "*" Then
            Set IE = New InternetExplorer
            With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57632973/delete-label-points-and-set-hover-text-and-legend-in-clustering-scatter-plot" 'CHANGE THIS
                While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                    DoEvents
                Wend
            Set HTMLdoc = .document
            If IE.Body Like "*" & "Page not found" & "*" Then
                myItem.Delete
            End If
            End With
        End If
      Next myItem
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If it is RSS I might condider switching to xmlhttp requests for small request numbers and check the status codes. You need to be careful though with number of requests and timings as SO can temp IP ban you.

Comment: Any reason not using the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  This is the solution!!

```
Sub GetRssItem()
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim subFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim myItem As Object
Dim IE As InternetExplorer

Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderRssFeeds)
For i = 1 To 27
Set subFolder = myFolder.Folders(i)
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

   Debug.Print subFolder
      For Each myItem In subFolder.Items
        If InStr(myItem.Subject, "[on hold]") > 0 Or _
            InStr(myItem.Subject, "[closed]") > 0 Then
            Debug.Print myItem.Subject
            myItem.Delete
        End If

        If myItem.Body Like "*" & "View article..." & "*" Then

            StartPos = InStr(myItem.Body, "View article...") + 17
            EndPos = InStrRev(myItem.Body, ">")
            myStr = Mid(myItem.Body, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos)

            With IE
            .Visible = False
            .navigate myStr

            While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Wend
            Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document
            If IE.Document.Body.innerHTML Like "*" & "Page not found" & "*" Then
                myItem.Delete
            End If
            End With
        End If


      Next myItem
Next i

IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: you only need one IE instance created outside loop

Comment: Thanks.  You probably know this stuff better than anyone I know.